# Java aes key to 32byte string representation

Tags: java, encoding, aes, symmetric-key

How can this be done? I want to take the resulting aes secretkey and turn it into the plaintext 16byte representation

```
        public SecretKey generateAesKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
                KeyGenerator keygen;
                keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                keygen.init(128);
                SecretKey aesKey = keygen.generateKey();
                return aesKey;
        }
```

Im using this to generate the key
(Pretty sure the key would be 32 bytes, unless I'm thinking of 256bit key?)

Answer (score 1):

`SecretKey` class has a method `.getEncoded()` which will return your key.

You can obtain your string representation in hexadecimal (for example) using the following method:

```
private static String bytesToHexRepresentation(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

therefore you can do:

```
SecretKey myKey = generateAesKey();
byte[] encodedBytes = myKey.getEncoded();
String s = bytesToHexRepresentation(encodedBytes);
System.out.printf(s);
```

To print your key in a nice hexadecimal representation.

As for your second question:

- for 128 bits the key is 16 bytes (your current case)
- for 192 bits the key is 24 bytes
- for 256 bits the key is 32 bytes